# Make a Select between two dates captured by JQuery Datepicker with Linq Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, datepicker

I'm using Database First, EF 6, Visual Studio 2013 Pro.

This is the code on Controller

```
    public ActionResult Index(string searchString, string datepicker, string datepicker2)
    {
        var transactions = db.transactions.Include(t => t.Client).Include(t => t.DocumentType).Include(t => t.MovementType1);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            transactions = transactions.Where(s => s.Client.Name.Contains(searchString) && 
                                              s.Date >= Convert.ToDateTime(datepicker) && s.Date < Convert.ToDateTime(datepicker2));     
        }
        return View(transaccions.ToList());
    }
```

It made the selection well when seach by client name.

This is the code of the View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 <p>
    Search Transactions by Name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") 
    First Date:  
                  <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
    Second Date: 
                   <input type="text" id="datepicker2"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</p> 
}
```

As you can see, I am capturing the dates through the selection made by the user in the datepicker.

I want to do this query: `SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION WHERE Client.Name LIKE (searchString) AND DATE BETWEEN (datepicker) AND (datepicker2)`.

I want to make the search by the customer's name and a date range.

The problem is that Linq doesnt recognize the convertion method.

I've been looking for a way to do it and none are compatible with my code.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the conversion outside of the Linq query:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString, string datepicker, string datepicker2)
{
    var transactions = db.transactions.Include(t => t.Client).Include(t => t.DocumentType).Include(t => t.MovementType1);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        //Get your dates here...
        var fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datepicker);
        var toDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datepicker2);

        transactions = transactions.Where(s => s.Client.Name.Contains(searchString) && 
                                          s.Date >= fromDate && s.Date < toDate);     
    }
    return View(transaccions.ToList());
}
```

Comment: I usually recommend to use a fixed format for the dateTimePicker and use `fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(datepicker, "yyyyMMdd", null);`

Comment: It would be better to explain that, he got this error, because `Entity Framework` does not know how to execute `Convert.ToDateTime` method in sql.

Comment: Works!! Thanks DavidG